# IE 8 does not catch the style with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Sparkline, a jQuery plugin for displaying inline charts in cells in a table. On clicking that chart, a modal opens up showing the chart. We are trying to set the background color for the modal as #FFF. It works fine in Firefox but for some reason doesn't work in IE 8. Is there anything I can do?

I have even tried doing this explicitly:

```
$("#elementid").css("background-color", "#FFF");
```

The modal shows a background color of black in IE 8 but it works perfectly well in Firefox.

This is the code that fires the chart , it is in a

```
<SPAN class= someclass onclick="GetHighChartData('something'); return false"><SPAN style="POSITION: relative; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 80px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 18px; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; OVERFLOW: hidden; PADDING-TOP: 0px" width="80" height="18"><?import namespace = v urn = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" implementation = "#default#VML" declareNamespace /><v:group style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 80px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" coordsize = "80,18"><v:shape style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 80px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; HEIGHT: 18px; TOP: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" coordsize = "80,18" filled = "t" fillcolor = "#cdf" stroked = "f" path = " m2,15 l2,7,6,5,10,2,13,5,17,10,21,10,25,7,29,7,32,10,36,7,40,7,44,5,48,12,51,7,55,7,59,10,63,10,67,7,70,13,74,14 78,15,78,14 e"> </v:shape><v:shape style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 80px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; HEIGHT: 18px; TOP: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" coordsize = "80,18" filled = "f" strokecolor = "blue" strokeweight = "1pt" path = " m2,7 l2,7,6,5,10,2,13,5,17,10,21,10,25,7,29,7,32,10,36,7,40,7,44,5,48,12,51,7,55,7,59,10,63,10,67,7,70,13,74,14 78,15 e"> </v:shape><v:oval style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 3px; HEIGHT: 3px; TOP: 12.5px; LEFT: 75.5px" coordsize = "21600,21600" filled = "t" fillcolor = "#f80" stroked = "f"></v:oval><v:oval style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 3px; HEIGHT: 3px; TOP: 12.5px; LEFT: 75.5px" coordsize = "21600,21600" filled = "t" fillcolor = "#f80" stroked = "f"></v:oval><v:oval style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 3px; HEIGHT: 3px; TOP: -0.5px; LEFT: 7.5px" coordsize = "21600,21600" filled = "t" fillcolor = "#f80" stroked = "f"></v:oval></v:group></SPAN></SPAN>
```

This is the code that has the inner HTML when the modal shows up.

```
<div id="simplemodal-container" class="simplemodal-container" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1002; height: 334px; width: 664px; left: 295.5px; top: -4px;"><a title="Close" class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close"></a><div tabindex="-1" class="simplemodal-wrap" style="height: 100%; outline: 0px none; width: 100%; overflow: auto;"><div class="highcharts-container simplemodal-data" id="container" style="display: block;"><div class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-0" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 600px; height: 410px; text-align: left; font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;,&quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; left: -0.5px; top: 0px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="410"><defs><clippath id="highcharts-1"><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="251" stroke-width="0"/></clippath><lineargradient id="highcharts-2" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#EEE" stop-opacity="1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/></lineargradient><lineargradient id="highcharts-3" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="14"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#CCC" stop-opacity="1"/></lineargradient><lineargradient id="highcharts-4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="14"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#CCC" stop-opacity="1"/></lineargradient><lineargradient id="highcharts-5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="14"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#CCC" stop-opacity="1"/></lineargradient></defs><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="transparent" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="410" stroke-width="0" stroke="transparent"/><g transform="translate(36, 382)"><rect fill="url(http://localhost:5379/index1.htm#highcharts-2)" x="0" y="-0.5" width="554" height="14" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC" rx="0" ry="0"/><rect fill="url(http://localhost:5379/index1.htm#highcharts-3)" x="14.5" y="-0.5" width="526" height="14" stroke-width="1" stroke="#666" rx="2" ry="2"/><path fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" d="M 273.5 3.5 L 273.5 9.333333333333334 M 276.5 3.5 L 276.5 9.333333333333334 M 279.5 3.5 L 279.5 9.333333333333334" visibility="visible"/><g><rect rx="2" ry="2" fill="url(http://localhost:5379/index1.htm#highcharts-4)" x="-0.5" y="-0.5" width="14" height="14" stroke-width="1" stroke="#666"/><path d="M 8 4 L 8 10 5 7" fill="#666"/></g><g transform="translate(540)"><rect rx="2" ry="2" fill="url(http://localhost:5379/index1.htm#highcharts-5)" x="-0.5" y="-0.5" width="14" height="14" stroke-width="1" stroke="#666"/><path d="M 6 4 L 6 10 9 7" fill="#666"/></g></g><text x="36" y="55" style="font-size: 12px;"><tspan x="36">Zoom</tspan></text><text x="300" y="25" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(62, 87, 111); fill: rgb(62, 87, 111);" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" zIndex="1"><tspan x="300">TreasuryConstant2Year</tspan></text><g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1"/><g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1"><path d="M 36 316.5 L 590 316.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 36 266.5 L 590 266.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 36 216.5 L 590 216.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 36 165.5 L 590 165.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 36 115.5 L 590 115.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 36 65.5 L 590 65.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/></g><g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1"><path d="M 195.5 341 L 195.5 381" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 342.5 341 L 342.5 381" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 489.5 341 L 489.5 381" fill="none" stroke="#C0C0C0" stroke-width="1"/></g><g class="highcharts-grid" zIndex="1"/><path d="M 41.5 65 L 41.5 316" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke="#C0C0C0" zIndex="2" visibility="hidden"/><g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3"><g class="highcharts-series" clip-path="url(http://localhost:5379/index1.htm#highcharts-1)" visibility="visible" transform="translate(36, 65)"><path d="M 5.431372549019608 150.60000000000002 L 16.285072896769034 150.60000000000002 L 27.138773244518458 110.44 L 37.992473592267885 110.44 L 48.84617394001731 150.60000000000002 L 59.69987428776673 170.68000000000004 L 70.55357463551616 170.68000000000004 L 81.40727498326558 170.68000000000004 L 92.26097533101502 150.60000000000002 L 103.11467567876444 150.60000000000002 L 113.96837602651387 70.28000000000006 L 124.82207637426329 50.200000000000045 L 135.6757767220127 10.04000000000002 L 146.52947706976215 10.04000000000002 L 157.38317741751158 10.04000000000002 L 168.236877765261 10.04000000000002 L 179.09057811301042 70.28000000000006 L 189.94427846075985 70.28000000000006 L 200.79797880850927 90.35999999999996 L 211.6516791562587 90.35999999999996 L 222.50537950400812 90.35999999999996 L 233.35907985175754 90.35999999999996 L 244.21278019950697 90.35999999999996 L 255.0664805472564 90.35999999999996 L 265.92018089500584 90.35999999999996 L 276.77388124275524 50.200000000000045 L 287.6275815905047 50.200000000000045 L 298.4812819382541 50.200000000000045 L 309.33498228600354 50.200000000000045 L 320.18868263375293 130.52 L 331.0423829815024 90.35999999999996 L 341.8960833292518 30.120000000000033 L 352.74978367700123 90.35999999999996 L 363.6034840247506 150.60000000000002 L 374.4571843725001 150.60000000000002 L 385.3108847202495 150.60000000000002 L 396.1645850679989 190.76 L 407.0182854157483 182.12559506893234 L 417.8719857634978 174.29441211223593 L 428.72568611124717 206.22161397934062 L 548.5686274509804 174.69598898887705" fill="none" stroke="#4572A7" stroke-width="2"/><path d="M 0 -4 C 5.328 -4 5.328 4 0 4 C -5.328 4 -5.328 -4 0 -4 Z" fill="#4572A7" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(5.43137, 150.6)" visibility="hidden"/></g><g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible" transform="translate(50, 341)"><path d="M 0 27.215965544865313 C 0 27.215965544865313 6.306744379683598 27.215965544865313 10.511240632805995 27.215965544865313 C 14.715736885928393 27.215965544865313 16.817985012489594 20.392356341570455 21.02248126561199 20.392356341570455 C 25.22697751873439 20.392356341570455 27.329225645295587 20.392356341570455 31.533721898417987 20.392356341570455 C 35.73821815154039 20.392356341570455 37.84046627810159 25.168882783876853 42.04496253122398 27.215965544865313 C 46.24945878434638 29.263048305853772 48.35170691090758 30.627770146512745 52.556203164029974 30.627770146512745 C 56.760699417152374 30.627770146512745 58.862947543713574 30.627770146512745 63.067443796835974 30.627770146512745 C 67.27194004995837 30.627770146512745 69.37418817651958 30.627770146512745 73.57868442964197 30.627770146512745 C 77.78318068276437 30.627770146512745 79.88542880932557 27.215965544865313 84.08992506244796 27.215965544865313 C 88.29442131557036 27.215965544865313 90.39666944213157 27.215965544865313 94.60116569525395 27.215965544865313 C 98.80566194837635 27.215965544865313 100.90791007493756 16.980551739923044 105.11240632805995 13.568747138275615 C 109.31690258118235 10.156942536628186 111.41915070774355 12.204025297616639 115.62364696086594 10.156942536628186 C 119.82814321398834 8.109859775639725 121.93039134054955 3.3333333333333286 126.13488759367195 3.3333333333333286 C 130.33938384679436 3.3333333333333286 132.44163197335556 3.3333333333333286 136.64612822647794 3.3333333333333286 C 140.85062447960036 3.3333333333333286 142.95287260616155 3.3333333333333286 147.15736885928393 3.3333333333333286 C 151.36186511240635 3.3333333333333286 153.46411323896754 3.3333333333333286 157.66860949208993 3.3333333333333286 C 161.87310574521234 3.3333333333333286 163.97535387177354 13.568747138275615 168.17985012489592 13.568747138275615 C 172.38434637801834 13.568747138275615 174.48659450457953 13.568747138275615 178.69109075770191 13.568747138275615 C 182.89558701082433 13.568747138275615 184.99783513738552 16.980551739923026 189.2023313905079 16.980551739923026 C 193.40682764363032 16.980551739923026 195.50907577019152 16.980551739923026 199.7135720233139 16.980551739923026 C 203.91806827643632 16.980551739923026 206.0203164029975 16.980551739923026 210.2248126561199 16.980551739923026 C 214.4293089092423 16.980551739923026 216.5315570358035 16.980551739923026 220.7360532889259 16.980551739923026 C 224.9405495420483 16.980551739923026 227.0427976686095 16.980551739923026 231.24729392173188 16.980551739923026 C 235.4517901748543 16.980551739923026 237.5540383014155 16.980551739923026 241.75853455453787 16.980551739923026 C 245.9630308076603 16.980551739923026 248.06527893422148 16.980551739923026 252.2697751873439 16.980551739923026 C 256.47427144046634 16.980551739923026 258.5765195670275 10.156942536628186 262.7810158201499 10.156942536628186 C 266.9855120732723 10.156942536628186 269.0877601998335 10.156942536628186 273.2922564529559 10.156942536628186 C 277.4967527060783 10.156942536628186 279.5990008326395 10.156942536628186 283.8034970857619 10.156942536628186 C 288.00799333888426 10.156942536628186 290.1102414654455 10.156942536628186 294.31473771856787 10.156942536628186 C 298.5192339716903 10.156942536628186 300.6214820982515 23.804160943217884 304.82597835137386 23.804160943217884 C 309.03047460449625 23.804160943217884 311.13272273105747 20.392356341570427 315.33721898417986 16.980551739923026 C 319.5417152373023 13.568747138275576 321.64396336386346 6.745137934980754 325.84845961698585 6.745137934980754 C 330.05295587010824 6.745137934980754 332.15520399666946 12.886386217946141 336.35970024979184 16.980551739923026 C 340.5641965029143 21.074717261899966 342.66644462947545 27.215965544865313 346.87094088259784 27.215965544865313 C 351.0754371357202 27.215965544865313 353.17768526228144 27.215965544865313 357.38218151540383 27.215965544865313 C 361.5866777685263 27.215965544865313 363.68892589508744 27.215965544865313 367.8934221482098 27.215965544865313 C 372.0979184013322 27.215965544865313 374.20016652789343 34.03957474816016 378.4046627810158 34.03957474816016 C 382.60915903413826 34.03957474816016 384.7114071606994 33.13203347468192 388.9159034138218 32.57249793161117 C 393.1203996669442 32.012962388540416 395.2226477935054 31.2418970328064 399.4271440466278 31.2418970328064 C 403.63164029975025 31.2418970328064 405.7338884263114 36.666666666666664 409.9383846794338 36.666666666666664 C 456.36303080766027 36.666666666666664 526 31.310129195935847 526 31.310129195935847 L 526 40 L 0 40" fill="rgb(69,114,167)" fill-opacity="0.4"/><path d="M 0 27.215965544865313 C 0 27.215965544865313 6.306744379683598 27.215965544865313 10.511240632805995 27.215965544865313 C 14.715736885928393 27.215965544865313 16.817985012489594 20.392356341570455 21.02248126561199 20.392356341570455 C 25.22697751873439 20.392356341570455 27.329225645295587 20.392356341570455 31.533721898417987 20.392356341570455 C 35.73821815154039 20.392356341570455 37.84046627810159 25.168882783876853 42.04496253122398 27.215965544865313 C 46.24945878434638 29.263048305853772 48.35170691090758 30.627770146512745 52.556203164029974 30.627770146512745 C 56.760699417152374 30.627770146512745 58.862947543713574 30.627770146512745 63.067443796835974 30.627770146512745 C 67.27194004995837 30.627770146512745 69.37418817651958 30.627770146512745 73.57868442964197 30.627770146512745 C 77.78318068276437 30.627770146512745 79.88542880932557 27.215965544865313 84.08992506244796 27.215965544865313 C 88.29442131557036 27.215965544865313 90.39666944213157 27.215965544865313 94.60116569525395 27.215965544865313 C 98.80566194837635 27.215965544865313 100.90791007493756 16.980551739923044 105.11240632805995 13.568747138275615 C 109.31690258118235 10.156942536628186 111.41915070774355 12.204025297616639 115.62364696086594 10.156942536628186 C 119.82814321398834 8.109859775639725 121.93039134054955 3.3333333333333286 126.13488759367195 3.3333333333333286 C 130.33938384679436 3.3333333333333286 132.44163197335556 3.3333333333333286 136.64612822647794 3.3333333333333286 C 140.85062447960036 3.3333333333333286 142.95287260616155 3.3333333333333286 147.15736885928393 3.3333333333333286 C 151.36186511240635 3.3333333333333286 153.46411323896754 3.3333333333333286 157.66860949208993 3.3333333333333286 C 161.87310574521234 3.3333333333333286 163.97535387177354 13.568747138275615 168.17985012489592 13.568747138275615 C 172.38434637801834 13.568747138275615 174.48659450457953 13.568747138275615 178.69109075770191 13.568747138275615 C 182.89558701082433 13.568747138275615 184.99783513738552 16.980551739923026 189.2023313905079 16.980551739923026 C 193.40682764363032 16.980551739923026 195.50907577019152 16.980551739923026 199.7135720233139 16.980551739923026 C 203.91806827643632 16.980551739923026 206.0203164029975 16.980551739923026 210.2248126561199 16.980551739923026 C 214.4293089092423 16.980551739923026 216.5315570358035 16.980551739923026 220.7360532889259 16.980551739923026 C 224.9405495420483 16.980551739923026 227.0427976686095 16.980551739923026 231.24729392173188 16.980551739923026 C 235.4517901748543 16.980551739923026 237.5540383014155 16.980551739923026 241.75853455453787 16.980551739923026 C 245.9630308076603 16.980551739923026 248.06527893422148 16.980551739923026 252.2697751873439 16.980551739923026 C 256.47427144046634 16.980551739923026 258.5765195670275 10.156942536628186 262.7810158201499 10.156942536628186 C 266.9855120732723 10.156942536628186 269.0877601998335 10.156942536628186 273.2922564529559 10.156942536628186 C 277.4967527060783 10.156942536628186 279.5990008326395 10.156942536628186 283.8034970857619 10.156942536628186 C 288.00799333888426 10.156942536628186 290.1102414654455 10.156942536628186 294.31473771856787 10.156942536628186 C 298.5192339716903 10.156942536628186 300.6214820982515 23.804160943217884 304.82597835137386 23.804160943217884 C 309.03047460449625 23.804160943217884 311.13272273105747 20.392356341570427 315.33721898417986 16.980551739923026 C 319.5417152373023 13.568747138275576 321.64396336386346 6.745137934980754 325.84845961698585 6.745137934980754 C 330.05295587010824 6.745137934980754 332.15520399666946 12.886386217946141 336.35970024979184 16.980551739923026 C 340.5641965029143 21.074717261899966 342.66644462947545 27.215965544865313 346.87094088259784 27.215965544865313 C 351.0754371357202 27.215965544865313 353.17768526228144 27.215965544865313 357.38218151540383 27.215965544865313 C 361.5866777685263 27.215965544865313 363.68892589508744 27.215965544865313 367.8934221482098 27.215965544865313 C 372.0979184013322 27.215965544865313 374.20016652789343 34.03957474816016 378.4046627810158 34.03957474816016 C 382.60915903413826 34.03957474816016 384.7114071606994 33.13203347468192 388.9159034138218 32.57249793161117 C 393.1203996669442 32.012962388540416 395.2226477935054 31.2418970328064 399.4271440466278 31.2418970328064 C 403.63164029975025 31.2418970328064 405.7338884263114 36.666666666666664 409.9383846794338 36.666666666666664 C 456.36303080766027 36.666666666666664 526 31.310129195935847 526 31.310129195935847" fill="none" stroke="#4572A7" stroke-width="1"/></g></g><rect fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="50" y="341" width="0" height="40" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.75" zIndex="3"/><rect fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="576" y="341" width="0" height="40" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.75" zIndex="3"/><path fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke="#444" zIndex="3" d="M 36 341.5 L 49.5 341.5 49.5 395.5 576.5 395.5 576.5 341.5 590 341.5"/><g style="" zIndex="3" transform="translate(50, 353)"><rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="#FFF" x="-4.5" y="0.5" width="8" height="15" stroke-width="1" stroke="#666"/><path d="M -1.5 4 L -1.5 12 M 0.5 4 L 0.5 12" fill="#FFF" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1"/></g><g style="" zIndex="3" transform="translate(576, 353)"><rect rx="3" ry="3" fill="#FFF" x="-4.5" y="0.5" width="8" height="15" stroke-width="1" stroke="#666"/><path d="M -1.5 4 L -1.5 12 M 0.5 4 L 0.5 12" fill="#FFF" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1"/></g><g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="7"><text x="39.1702" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="39.1702">26. Sep</tspan></text><text x="115.146" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="115.146">3. Oct</tspan></text><text x="191.122" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="191.122">10. Oct</tspan></text><text x="267.098" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="267.098">17. Oct</tspan></text><text x="343.074" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="343.074">24. Oct</tspan></text><text x="419.05" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="419.05">31. Oct</tspan></text><text x="495.026" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="495.026">7. Nov</tspan></text><text x="571.002" y="330" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="571.002">14. Nov</tspan></text><path d="M 39.5 316 L 39.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 115.5 316 L 115.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 191.5 316 L 191.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 267.5 316 L 267.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 343.5 316 L 343.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 419.5 316 L 419.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 495.5 316 L 495.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M 571.5 316 L 571.5 321" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/></g><g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="7"><text x="38" y="314" style="font-size: 11px; width: 257px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="38">0.2</tspan></text><text x="38" y="263.8" style="font-size: 11px; width: 257px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="38">0.225</tspan></text><text x="38" y="213.6" style="font-size: 11px; width: 257px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="38">0.25</tspan></text><text x="38" y="163.4" style="font-size: 11px; width: 257px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="38">0.275</tspan></text><text x="38" y="113.2" style="font-size: 11px; width: 257px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="38">0.3</tspan></text></g><text x="26" y="190.5" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(109, 134, 159); font-weight: bold; fill: rgb(109, 134, 159);" zIndex="7" transform="rotate(270, 26, 190)" text-anchor="middle"><tspan x="26">Rates</tspan></text><g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="7"><text x="197.968" y="377" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="197.968">10. Oct</tspan></text><text x="345.125" y="377" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="345.125">24. Oct</tspan></text><text x="492.282" y="377" style="font-size: 11px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); line-height: 14px; fill: rgb(102, 102, 102);" text-anchor="start"><tspan x="492.282">7. Nov</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="7"/><path d="M 36 316.5 L 590 316.5" fill="none" stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1" zIndex="7"/><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="116" height="42" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0.85" zIndex="8" visibility="hidden" isShadow="true" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(1, 158)"/><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="116" height="42" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity="0.85" zIndex="8" visibility="hidden" isShadow="true" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(1, 158)"/><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="116" height="42" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.85" zIndex="8" visibility="hidden" isShadow="true" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(1, 158)"/><rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="0" y="0" width="116" height="42" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.85" zIndex="8" visibility="hidden" stroke="#4572A7" transform="translate(0, 157)"/><text x="5" y="171" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); padding: 0pt; white-space: nowrap; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);" zIndex="8" visibility="hidden"><tspan style="font-size: 10px;" x="5">Monday, Sep 26, 2011</tspan><tspan style="fill: rgb(69, 114, 167);" dy="18" x="5">Rate</tspan><tspan dx="3">: </tspan><tspan style="font-weight: bold;" dx="3">0.25</tspan></text><text x="590" y="405" style="font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(144, 144, 144); fill: rgb(144, 144, 144);" text-anchor="end" zIndex="8"><tspan x="590">Highstock Beta</tspan></text><g class="highcharts-tracker" zIndex="9" transform="translate(36, 65)"><path d="M -4.568627450980392 150.60000000000002 L 5.431372549019608 150.60000000000002 L 16.285072896769034 150.60000000000002 L 27.138773244518458 110.44 L 37.992473592267885 110.44 L 48.84617394001731 150.60000000000002 L 59.69987428776673 170.68000000000004 L 70.55357463551616 170.68000000000004 L 81.40727498326558 170.68000000000004 L 92.26097533101502 150.60000000000002 L 103.11467567876444 150.60000000000002 L 113.96837602651387 70.28000000000006 L 124.82207637426329 50.200000000000045 L 135.6757767220127 10.04000000000002 L 146.52947706976215 10.04000000000002 L 157.38317741751158 10.04000000000002 L 168.236877765261 10.04000000000002 L 179.09057811301042 70.28000000000006 L 189.94427846075985 70.28000000000006 L 200.79797880850927 90.35999999999996 L 211.6516791562587 90.35999999999996 L 222.50537950400812 90.35999999999996 L 233.35907985175754 90.35999999999996 L 244.21278019950697 90.35999999999996 L 255.0664805472564 90.35999999999996 L 265.92018089500584 90.35999999999996 L 276.77388124275524 50.200000000000045 L 287.6275815905047 50.200000000000045 L 298.4812819382541 50.200000000000045 L 309.33498228600354 50.200000000000045 L 320.18868263375293 130.52 L 331.0423829815024 90.35999999999996 L 341.8960833292518 30.120000000000033 L 352.74978367700123 90.35999999999996 L 363.6034840247506 150.60000000000002 L 374.4571843725001 150.60000000000002 L 385.3108847202495 150.60000000000002 L 396.1645850679989 190.76 L 407.0182854157483 182.12559506893234 L 417.8719857634978 174.29441211223593 L 428.72568611124717 206.22161397934062 L 548.5686274509804 174.69598898887705 L 558.5686274509804 174.69598898887705" fill="none" isTracker="true" stroke-opacity="0.000001" stroke="rgb(192,192,192)" stroke-width="22" visibility="visible" zIndex="1"/></g></svg></div><div style="position: relative; height: 0pt; font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;,&quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: -370px; right: 10px;"><span>From:</span><input type="text" name="min" class="highcharts-range-selector" style="width: 80px; height: 16px; border: 1px solid silver; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; text-align: center;"><span>To:</span><input type="text" name="max" class="highcharts-range-selector" style="width: 80px; height: 16px; border: 1px solid silver; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0pt; text-align: center;"></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: That should work. There must be something else going on. Can you show more code?

Comment: may be your HTML is wrong . please post your HTML code

Comment: Validate your HTML - http://validator.w3.org/ - And validate your JavaScript - http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: Why not do this in pure CSS? `#elementId { background-color: #fff; }`

Answer (score 2):

Try to see if that works:

```
$("#elementid").css("background-color", "#FFF !important");
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the times this can cause because of your incorrect HTML . if you have wrong HTML tags , in IE the javascripts dont work properly .

also you need to add the DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The doctype declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of the markup language the page is written in.

The doctype declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

try this . with out posting code , can not help much

Comment: New web pages have no need for the transitional doctype. That is only for pages that still use deprecated markup and are transitioning to current code. Always use strict otherwise.

Comment: guys I have posted some code. If you guys could give some suggestions and ideas that would be great.